# Snap interface - getting the Time

Tags: haskell, time, haskell-snap-framework

I am using the Snap interface and I am wondering if there is a function ':: Request -> Time'.
(Or CTime).

I would like to get the time when someone visits the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request` does not have any time in it (you can check this from [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Http-Types.html#Request)).

But you can get current time while handling request:

```
import Data.Time.Clock (getCurrentTime)
import Data.Time.Format
import qualified Data.Text as T

someHandler :: Handler App App ()
someHandler = do
  utcTime <- liftIO getCurentTime
  writeText $ T.pack $ formatTime undefined "%F %T" utcTime
```